# Google map api save visit history

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I choose with the marker where  I want to save in a div. For example I choose a place lat=35 lng=41. I want to save this location. Later I choose another a place. Then I want to save in the div. Here my example http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/QvNUF

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
zoom: 1,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.137879, -82.836914),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });
var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.651968, 9.478485),
draggable: true
   });
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</p>';
   });
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging     marker...</p>';
   });
map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
myMarker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to load jquery first
then here below the adjusted code

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.137879, -82.836914),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.651968, 9.478485),
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: <div id="lat" data-lat="' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + '">' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + '</div> Current Lng: <div id="long" data-long="' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '">' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</div></p>';
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
});

map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
myMarker.setMap(map);

   $( "#saving" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log($( "#lat" ).data('lat'));
  console.log($("#long").data("long"));
});
```

then instead of console.log use the proper ajax call you can use ajaxform jquery plugin using the following [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

to send it to your server side file that will communicate with a database or store it in json/xml file for future need

the HTML will be something like this

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div id='map_canvas'></div>
        <div id="current">Nothing yet...</div>
        <button id="saving" type="button">save Me!</button>
    </section>
</body>
```

another code without jquery form plugin

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.137879, -82.836914),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.651968, 9.478485),
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: <div id="lat" data-lat="' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + '">' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + '</div> Current Lng: <div id="long" data-long="' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '">' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</div></p>';
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
});

map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
myMarker.setMap(map);

   $( "#saving" ).on( "click", function() {
   var lat=$("#lat").data("lat");
   var long=$("#long").data("long");
$.post( "yourserverfile.php/jsp/asp", { lat: lat, long: long } function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
});
```

another code to store it in browser localstorage noneed to database engine
change the on click even as follows

```
   $( "#saving" ).on( "click", function() {
   var lat=$("#lat").data("lat");
   var long=$("#long").data("long");
 localStorage.setItem("lat", lat);
 localStorage.setItem("long", long);

//to read from local storage use 
localStorage.getItem("lat"); 
 localStorage.getItem("long");
    });
```

here is a general example 
http://jsfiddle.net/HATEMOVICH/yLfevs0z/1/

Comment: didnt work anything and this code just take lat and lng coordinates it wont save anywhere.

Comment: i updated the code , you need to check the console , its working now , however you need to specify which language you are using on the server side so i can help further i just wrote what you where missing in your code @AaronSterling

Comment: if you need futher help with server side page , just ask :) just remmeber to escape before storing to database , however its not recommended to use a database it seems a simple application , also localstorage might not work on old browsers , use a json object instead @AaronSterling